# Why does iOS 11 SDK written in objc unable to build on iOS14 swift project , but iOS13 does?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, sdk

I was trying to change the minimum deployment from iOS 13 to iOS 14 of my app, however Xcode throws these error:

```
ld: unaligned pointer(s) for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Once switch back to iOS 13, my app can build and run smoothly.

As far as I know, the minimum deployment of this SDK is iOS 11.0, and it's a static .a file, not xcframework I used to see, is there any approach that can embed this SDK into Swift projects that above iOS 13, without  changing the code of SDK, just modify it's setting?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Check parameters of supported architectures. I suggest to remove any if specified. Also if you are using cocopods, you need manually rise deployment target in all pods. Doesn't know why cocoapods not doing it automatically.

Comment: @Cy-4AH The setup of  supported architectures is standard(arm64), and Build Active Architecture Only is No when releasing, Yes when Debugging, also feels same about cocapods.